# How to import an eth account with keystore and password on iOS?

Tags: ios, ethereum, keystore, go-ethereum, geth

I work on iOS  and use "Geth" lib. I want to create or import an account with exist keystore file(not encrypted) and I have address and password. with the 3 parameters, how can I restore or import an account?

and the 3 parameters are:
1) keystorefile :

```
"{\"version\":3,\"id\":\"6c4a68bd-52dc-4581-b641-5d0226e1c8f2\",\"address\":\"a84cef392157c2317066bcd2b9ae3de51cbfa665\",\"crypto\":{\"ciphertext\":\"fd582f8a4bbd9b0d5ef1da635844385074907f6db16aa4b587c64abcc5bc16d3\",\"cipherparams\":{\"iv\":\"28f6083deb8ecb112bf44f768811972b\"},\"cipher\":\"aes-128-ctr\",\"kdf\":\"scrypt\",\"kdfparams\":{\"dklen\":32,\"salt\":\"183d686781deaec13d608dab92f646928d0fda34c40e4e3ccbeb1f3b9d70bea5\",\"n\":8192,\"r\":8,\"p\":1},\"mac\":\"5e2fc202fd2ebf424cabb66a40148a8d635ff8227ecacdf21decc31fd5c039bb\"}}
```

2) password:111111

3) address : 0xa84cef392157c2317066bcd2b9ae3de51cbfa666

and I want use these 3 parameters to create a 'GethAccount' .

but i don't find any method thay can achive that. please help me.

Comment: Can you please share some code ? what 3 parameters ?

Comment: @Mosbah Hey, I have add some code , can you please to see it again?